# Attaching to process over SSH with VS2019 and ASP.NET core not working

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am running an asp.net docker container remotely.  I have enabled SSH, mapped the port and also installed VSDBG in the container.

In visual studio I am able to attach to process over SSH.  I choose my project dll file.  There are no error alerts and it appears to be debugging but on every breakpoint there is this message:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The breakpoint is pending and will be resolved when debugging starts.

Also if I open modules window there is no entries.

What is going on?  Why is remoe debugging not working?

Answer (score 1):

There are usually two reasons:
1. project publication made with release instead of debug configuration
2. the projects are not consistent. There is a difference between the project on the local machine and the server.